# laravel share variable in all views as reference

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I really want a very simple thing

1) I Share a global variable from AppServiceProvider like below

```
public function boot() {
    view()->share('css', new CSS());
}
```

2) I set some property values it In a View (index.blade.php) like blow

```
$css->publicProperty = "Something"; // changed in index.blade.php
```

3) In another View (contact.blade.php) i check the ***$css->publicProperty***  variable but it doesn't give me the change value

```
dd($css->publicProperty) // give me the initial value in contact.blade.php
```

Now i need a way that share a variable as **global** also as **reference**.

So that i change in one view and it will retain the change in other views also.

Comment: You could use a service to manage the data and inject it into your template, like described in the manual: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#service-injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#service-injection). Or you extend blade.

Comment: You can use something like this: https://github.com/twosuperior/registry

Comment: @CodeSpirit I also try with ServiceProvider and Facade but result is same

Comment: Are you setting the updated values before the `contact.blade.php` has been rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You should use session on your controller.

Set session like this:

```
Session::put('name','css');
```

And you can change that in view like this:

```
 {{Session::put('name','css')}}
```